# How to Make boot directory bigger?

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, upgrade, sudo

I have plenty space on my HD 420 GB but very little for boot directory & i can't upgrade to ubuntu 16.04
what is the eseyist way to inlarge the boot directory?

Comment: But that answer just suggested removing old kernels, not actually resizing /boot.  Do you need a separate /boot partition? (encrypted LVM root, old computer needs kernels near beginning of disk,... are reasons you might need /boot. Usually you don't.

Comment: @ubfan1 Your points were valid. I've added an answer to the duplicate to resize `/boot`. You might want to add another answer taking encryption into account (I don't use LVM).